# Image classification with large images

Tags: neural-networks, image-processing, keras

I am new to image classification and hope to set up a model which will classify large images (I am using R keras). Each image will represent a 10m by 10m square with pixels representing 1 cm. I need the fine resolution to capture the detail in the images. 
I can follow and run the keras examples for "regular" images with less pixels, like the MNIST data or images of cars or fruits. However, I don't have my real data yet so I am unsure what will happen if I attempt to use images with 1M pixels.

My question is:

- Is it possible to use images this large?
- If so, are there any special considerations I need to take into
  account or special processing that would be required?
- Where is a good place to start?

Comment: Questions that are only about software (e.g. error messages, code or packages, etc.)
are generally off topic here. If you have a substantive machine learning or
statistical question, please edit to clarify.

Comment: I have removed a reference to R, to make it, what I believe, on-topic (although it is still a bit broad but @DeltaIV [seems to know a way to answer it](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5587/is-this-question-mentioning-keras-off-topic)). I wanted to also add tags like data processing, computation performance, scaling/scalability, but they do not exist yet here. Questions about this are also not a lot seen here. I imagine that this question might fit well/better/also at datascience.stackexchange

Comment: 1M pixels is not that many, but your accuracy will probably be ok using much smaller images

Comment: you need to be more specific about your classification task

Comment: You should specify in detail the task of your classification, because you can benefit from preprocessing. Here there is a useful [link](https://tensorflow.rstudio.com/guides/keras/preprocessing_layers) that can help you. Depending on the model built, the image values may need a rescale. For example ResNet50V2 requires that these values are in the range [-1,1]. Also, you should pay attention if the images has all the same dimension or not. In the second case, you need to resize them if you want to use a batch size different than 1.